# How can I define a setup and teardown function for a specific method or function in pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Pytest supports [classical xunit style setup and teardown](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#classic-xunit-style-setup) on the module/class/method/function level (in addition to [pytests dependency injection mechanism](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html?highlight=dependency%20injection#fixtures-a-prime-example-of-dependency-injection)). The function level [setup and teardown functions are invoked for every test function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown) in the module. How can I define setup and teardown functions for specific test functions?

Comment: This is not what setup and teardown is intended for. The whole concept is for making common behavior for whole scope not for individual but than after you can set condition by identifying test name before setup and tear down.

Comment: Mh, ok. I could define a test class and place the test with its specific setup and teardown functions as well, right?

Comment: Yeah, Of course you can and if its only about single test, its better to include those steps into the test itself.

Comment: But how is the syntax then? (The teardown part must be "Marked" as such otherwise it is not executed if the test fails.)

Comment: ...wrapping the execution part into a `try` block and the teardown parts into `except` and `final`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def resource():
   resource = foo()

   yield resource

   resource.cleanup()

def test_feature(resource):
   assert bar(resource) == 27
```

Using fixtures for setup and cleanup is a better approach that the `try...finally` suggested in the question comments, even when there is no code reuse goal: your single test is focused on asserting the appropriate conditions, and not on resource cleanup.

Comment: I found the answer meanwhile [in the pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture-finalization-executing-teardown-code) as well.